# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when unarchiving Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I'm trying to unarchive a custom object that implements the the `NSCoding` protocol. This class is called `Reservation` and one of its property is a Swift dictionary:

```
class Reservation {
  //...
  var orderedExtras : [CarExtra : Int]?
}
```

`CarExtra` also implements `NSCoding`.
Now when I try to write the file to disk using

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(reservations, toFile: ArchiveURL.path!)
```

everything is fine. However, I have problems reading this object from disk.
When I try to unarchive the object with

```
 required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      let extras = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("orderedExtras") as? [CarExtra : Int]
 }
```

it gives me a

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)

exception. If I try to treat the unarchived object instead as an NSDictionary

```
let extras = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("orderedExtras") as? NSDictionary
```

it does not crash and I can extract the data I've saved.
Can someone explain why I get this error message? Of could simply use a NSDictionary throughout the application, but I would prefer to continue with the Swift types.

EDIT: Here is the stack trace
[image: stack trace]

Comment: how about as? NSDictionary as? [CarExtra : Int]
does this work?

Comment: Would you give an stack trace on EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION?

Comment: I updated the question. Unfortunately the as? NSDictionary as?  [CarExtra : Int] does not work, too.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it.

The archiving and unarchiving mechanism works fine. The problem was that I was trying to archive an object of type `[CarExtra: Int]?`. So I tried to archive an Optional. If you are then trying to cast it as an `[CarExtra : Int]` (notice the missing ?) you get a

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)

error.

So the solution is to archive a Swift Dictionary that is not an optional by simply unwrapping it. Make sure that the dict is not nil. For that you could use the `??` operator

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    //make sure that the dictionary is not nil before
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.orderedExtras!, forKey: "orderedExtras")

}
```

Notice the ! when encoding the object.
Then you can cast it back to a dictionary.

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      let extras = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("orderedExtras") as? [CarExtra : Int]
 }
```